# actualizar tabla en SQL

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, conexión

Hola buenas nose si me podríais ayudar, estoy haciendo una consulta SQL para actualizar unos datos de una tabla atreves de php, pero no consigo que funcione y tampoco me da ningún error, por lo que en apariencia no encuentro el problema. La cosa es que a través de un formulario y pasándole por Get el id del post que quiero actualizar una vez cambiados los datos en el formulario lo envió y no me da error, pero no se actualiza ni siquiera en la base de datos.

```
$errores=''; //declaramos la variable de errores en vacio para luego podeer montar los errores

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //le prefuntamos si a seteado la variable super --(que se halla dado al boton )
    //saneamos los datos
    $id=$sanearDato($_POST['id']);
    $titulo=$sanearDato($_POST['titulo']);
    $presentacion=$sanearDato($_POST['presentacion']);
    $descripcion=$sanearDato($_POST['descripcion']);

    $recorrido=$sanearDato($_POST['recorrido']);
    $elevacion=$sanearDato($_POST['elevacion']);
    $distancia=$sanearDato($_POST['distancia']);
    $dificultad=$sanearDato($_POST['dificultad']);

    $imagen_guardada=$sanearDato($_POST['imagen_guardada']);

    $imagen=$_FILES['imagen'];


    if(empty($titulo)){
        $errores.='<li>Debes rellenar el Título</li>';
    }

    if(empty($presentacion)){
        $errores.='<li>Debes rellenar la presentacion</li>';
    }

    if(empty($descripcion)){
        $errores.='<li>Debes rellenar La Descripción</li>';
    }



    if(empty($recorrido)){
        $errores.='<li>Debes rellenar el recorrido</li>';
    }

    if(empty($elevacion)){
        $errores.='<li>Debes rellenar la elevacion</li>';
    }

    if(empty($distancia)){
        $errores.='<li>Debes rellenar la distancia</li>';
    }

    if(empty($dificultad)){
        $errores.='<li>Debes rellenar la dificultad</li>';
    }

        if(empty($imagen['tmp_name'])){//si no hay imagen sera la que tengamos almacenada
            $imagen=$imagen_guardada; //si no se sube una nueva imagen se respetara la que ya tenemos
        }else{
             $comprobar=getimagesize($imagen["tmp_name"]); //con este metodo comprobamos que sea una imagen 

            if($comprobar==false){ // si da false sacamos el error)
                 $errores.='<li>El archivo no es una imagen</li>';
            }else{//en caso contrario subimos el archivo
                 $rutaDestino=$admin_config['rutaImg'].$imagen['name']; 
            
                 move_uploaded_file($imagen['tmp_name'], $rutaDestino);//esto lo almacena en un estapacio temporal del servidor
                 $imagen=$imagen['name'];

            }
        }

        $id=$recogerId(); //capturamos el id

        if(empty($errores)){ //si no hay errores editamos la ruta
            $editarPost($id,$titulo,$presentacion,$descripcion,$recorrido,$elevacion,$distancia,$dificultad,$imagen,'rutas');
            header("Location:admin.index.php");
        }

}else{ //en caso contrario traemos las rutas para pintarlas
    $id=$recogerId(); //capturamos el id

    if(!$id){ //si no hay rutas con ese id nos lleva al index del admin
        header("Location:admin.index.php");
    }

    $single=$recogerRutasPorId($id,'rutas'); //recogemos la ruta

    if(!$single){ //si no hay rutas(post) nos lleva al index del admin
        header("Location:admin.index.php");

       
}

}


$editarPost=function($id, $titulo, $presentacion, $descripcion, $recorrido,$elevacion, $distancia, $dificultad, $imagen, $tabla) use($conexion) {

    $stmt=$conexion()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET titulo=:titulo,presentacion=:presentacion,descripcion=:descripcion,recorrido=:recorrido,elevacion=:elevacion,distancia=:distancia,dificultad=:dificultad,imagen=:imagen WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->execute([
        ':titulo'=>$titulo,
        ':presentacion'=>$presentacion,
        ':descripcion'=>$descripcion,
        ':recorrido'=>$recorrido,
        ':elevacion'=>$elevacion,
        ':distancia'=>$distancia,
        ':dificultad'=>$dificultad,
        ':imagen'=>$imagen,
        ':id'=>$id,
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Antes de comenzar a obtener los datos, agrega la siguiente línea: `var_dump($_GET, $_POST); die();` que mostrará lo que se está enviando por URL y formulario y terminará la ejecución del script. Edita la pregunta para pegar el resultado.

Comment: envia los datos actualizados pero no los sube a la base de datos

Comment: Por eso es que te pido que pongas el resultado del `var_dump()` en la pregunta, específicamente, dices _"pasándole por Get el id del post"_, pero estás buscando el ID en otro lado con `$id=$sanearDato($_POST['id']);` y, más adelante, también tienes `$id=$recogerId();`

Comment: perdon se lo estoy pasando por post que me equivoque

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que al obtener el objeto `$conexion` (imagino que estás usando PDO), no esté configurado para que genere las excepciones.
Puedes hacer esto de la siguiente manera:

```php
    // Ejemplo de conexión a la base de datos 
    $dbConnection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
    
    // Establecer las propiedades, establecer en modo de Excepción
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: hola michael muchas gracias , aun asi creo que no es ese el problema, te enseño como lo tengo configurado.     $conexion=function() use($dsn,$userDB,$passDB){ // use hereda del cofing la variables que necesitamos para hacer la conexion
    try{
        return new PDO($dsn,$userDB,$passDB);
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        header('Location:error.php?error='.$e->getCode()); //levamos a la pagina error.php pasandole el codigo del error 
    }
};

Comment: Por defecto, PHP tiene el manejo de errores en modo `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`, si quisieras ver cuál fue el error que se genero, entonces tendrías que usar las funciones `$conexion->errorCode()` y `$conexion->errorInfo()` después de preparar o ejecutar la consulta que actualiza la información.

Te comparto el link donde puedes revisar la documentación completa: https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: muchisimas gracias lo intentare asi.